# HERE Maps binding with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, here-api, java-binding

I'm trying to build an app using the [HERE Mobile SDK](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/overview.html) (SDK for Android Premium).

I would like to bind it with Xamarin. But unfortunately there is no guide for this binding, although there was a component in the [Xamarin store](https://components.xamarin.com/) (which is no longer available, deprecated). There is only a [guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html) for Android-Studio.

I tried to stay as close as possible according to the Android-Studio guide.

---

### What I have done so far:

1. Create new bindings library
   [image: Create new bindings library]
2. Add the .JAR-file (in my case only the HERE-sdk.jar (I don't need the gson.jar or the javadoc.jar for testing purpose)) and set the build action to "EmbeddedJar"

[image: Jar-binding]

3. Afterwards I built the project and I got one error, which I solved after researching a bit
   [image: Error]
   [image: Solution to previous error.]
4. After I solved the previous error, I got 60 new error...
   [image]

**I tried to solve them with removing the nodes in the metadata.xml-file, but I think this is not the right solution for this problem...**

How do I solve this?
I tried to changed the return-types, managedNames and so on (according to this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/java-bindings-metadata/#Metadata.xml_Transform_File)), but none of this worked.

Also there is someone on the [Xamarin-forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43630/xamarin-binding-for-here-maps-problem), who had the same problem as me, but he couldn't solve it either.

*I am not that experienced with the metadata.xml - files. Maybe I misunderstood something.*

I would really appreciate some help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry we currently do not support Xamarin. It seems Xamarin has some trouble processing our pro-guarded jars. It was reported to us as well, but at the moment we are not investigating this.

Comment: Is it possibile i.e. to create simple Android app with HERE SDK and use it from another one by simple requests? i.e. navigate from A->B?

Comment: Sure, that would work. If you setup your activity to receive intents and put in the start and end points. (Or just end point if you want to navigate from current position). That should work nicely and easily with xamarin.